# Getting the average online time of users

Tags: python

I was tasked to process a log file that looks something like this:

```
bob logged-in 11:21:01 pm
bob logged-out 11:23:22 pm 
alice logged-in 11:24:12 pm
jane logged-in 11:31:00 pm
alice logged-out 11:34:20 pm
jane logged-out 11:55:00 pm
bob logged-n 11:56:01 pm
```

etc etc.

I need to create a script that displays how much time they were logged in for, in average. The output ought to look like:

```
jane: 12.5 mins
alice: 2.3 mins
bob: 2.2 mins
```

One user can login multiple times.
The file is sorted by time, and the login/logout entries are not sequential.

I'm looking for a bash or python solution to this, even if without solving the issue of the difficult timestamps (let's assume I've found a way to convert a partial timestamp like that to epoch format).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The hard part is matching the logout to the login so I can subtract themBest I could think of is: for every user, create two lists: one for login times and one for logout times, and then subtract logout[0] from login[0], logout[1] minus login[1] etc etc. It feels cumbersome, wondering if there's a cleaner way.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that after every time a user logs in he should log out before logging again you could do this.

Make 2 loops the first loop catches all log ins the second loop catches all log outs

Your setup should look like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
from functools import  reduce
lines = []
with open('logs.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

times = {}
```

Your first loop should look something like this:

```
for i in range(len(lines)):
    split_login = lines[i].split(' ')
    if split_login[1] != 'logged-in':
        continue
    name = split_login[0]
    # take the login time from the splitted line
    login_time = split_login[2] + split_login[3].replace('\n', '')
    # converted to datetime object
    login_time = datetime.strptime(login_time, '%I:%M:%S%p')
    # create dictionary in times dictionary where you store time per user
    if name not in times:
        times[name] = {'times': [], 'avg': 0}
```

Now the second loop should be an inner loop which will start from the index where the 
first loop is.

```
    for ii in range(len(lines)):
        if i+ii+1 < len(lines):
            split_logout = lines[ii+i+1].split(' ')
            if split_logout[0] == name:
                # take the logout time from the splitted line
                logout_time = split_logout[2] + split_login[3].replace('\n', '')
                # convert to datetime object
                logout_time = datetime.strptime(logout_time, '%I:%M:%S%p')
                # calc how long the login was
                time_logged = logout_time - login_time
                # append to the times of the user
                times[name]['times'].append(time_logged.total_seconds())
                # get the average
                times[name]['avg'] = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, times[name]['times']) / len(times[name]['times'])
                break
#print the avg times per user
for k, v in times.items():
    print('%s: %d' % (k, v['avg']/60))
```

This is just an quick and dirty example of how you could do it, i'm sure there are better ways and ofcourse the code could be cleaned as there are some duplicates.

Comment: Thanks! Much appreciated. I'll give this a test run.